# Using PDO Prepared Statements With MySQL Query Variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to increment rows in a table using PHP PDO and i have come up with this query

```
UPDATE users SET log = ?
```

I am trying to make an update based on the previous value on each column of the log

So, if my table was like this earlier

`+----+------+------+-----------+--------+
 | id | name | age  | eye_color | log    |
 +----+------+------+-----------+--------+
 | 21 | OLa  |   19 | black     |      1 |
 | 22 | OLa  |   19 | Green     |      2 |
 | 23 | OLa  |   19 | Grey      |      3 |
 +----+------+------+-----------+--------+`

Am expecting to get this result

`+----+------+------+-----------+--------+
 | id | name | age  | eye_color | log    |
 +----+------+------+-----------+--------+
 | 21 | OLa  |   19 | black     |      2 |
 | 22 | OLa  |   19 | Green     |      3 |
 | 23 | OLa  |   19 | Grey      |      4 |
 +----+------+------+-----------+--------+`

I found out i could make the value of my placeholder to be

```
log + 1
```

There by making the full query

```
UPDATE users SET log = log + 1
```

This works well when i use the PDO's query method and also from my terminal, the problem comes when I try updating this using prepared statements, If i did

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET log = ?");
$stml->execute(['height + 1']);
```

Then all the log columns becomes 0.

Is there anything am doing wrong? I also know i can just make the query plain

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET log = log + 1");
$stmt->execute(['log + 1']);
```

But i would prefer my initial approach, i am working with some constraints.

Comment: The query execute where you used `height + 1` what is height supposed to be? With the single quotes around it you are passing a literal string to the update which is not what you intended.

Comment: You need `UPDATE users SET log = height + ?` and `$stml->execute(['1']);`

Comment: the height is suppose to be the previous value of the height from the db table, sql works that way

Comment: Additionally, you have a typo: `$stmt` vs `$stml`

Comment: Your table examples did not include a height column. The answer MonkeyZeus provided is what you want.

Comment: This post make absolutely no sense. If you need `height + 1` then why does your code show `log + 1`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus / Dave It was a typo, editted

Comment: Why do you want to parameterize query? Is anything being passed as value from PHP, the application layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use query parameters to insert expressions to your syntax. Parameters are not just string-interpolation. If they were, there would be no benefit to using them, because you can do string-interpolation easily in PHP already.

The whole point of query parameters is that the value is combined with the query on the server, *after* the SQL syntax has been parsed, so it's too late for you to insert any new syntax, like an expression.

Query parameters are always treated as a single scalar value. You can't use a parameter for:

- Table identifiers
- Column identifiers
- SQL keywords
- Expressions
- Lists of values

As others have explained, in this case, you have no need to use a query parameter anyway. Using the literal expression `log + 1` directly in your query is safe. There's no untrusted content (from users or other sources) being inserted into the query, so there's no risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not getting information from the user, and is to sum 1 to a column you are safe executing a regular query.

```
UPDATE users SET log = log + 1
```

If you use a prepare statement you will have to query the column get the current value and then on the second query do the update and add 1 to it.